# CSS: z-index doesn't work, when I check in smartphone browser

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, z-index, menubar

I have a question about my responsive website.

I deployed my project to web server. In my local server and PC web server, I checked in google chrome dev tool, and z-index worked properly. The menu bar slides from the left side to the right side.

But when I checked in the real browser from a smartphone, the menu field did not show up. Background color and letter color are invisible.

When I tap each a tags (tags are invisible but I guessed each position.), I could jump to each page such as a result page, login page, and homepage. So I guess the menu bar is at the top of the screen.

The question is that,

> when I see a responsive website, the menu bar doesn't appear and is
>   invisible. But a tags inside the menu are working properly so, I
>   cannot figure out what this problem is coming from.

```css
.logo {
  line-height: 50px;
  float: left;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
}

.header {
  height: 50px;
  background: #2D2524;
  padding: 0 20px;
  color: white;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.header2 {
  display: none;
}

.menu {
  float: right;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.menu a {
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.background-img {
  background: url("../LPImages/karina-lago-wEucG_sLRsY-unsplash.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 70vh;
}

.main_search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  width: 70%;
  text-align: center;
}

.search_text {
  background: #232323;
  opacity: 0.9;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border: solid 3px #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 35%;
  height: 3rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
}

.search_text:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.Genre {
  color: #fff;
  background: #232323;
  opacity: 0.9;
  border: solid 3px #fff;
  padding-left: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 3.4rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.Genre:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.search_date {
  background: #232323;
  opacity: 0.8;
  margin-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  border: solid 3px #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 20%;
  font-weight: 400;
  height: 3rem;
}

.search_date:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.search_icon {
  color: #fff;
}

.show-menu-btn, .hide-menu-btn {
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

.show-menu-btn {
  float: right;
}

.show-menu-btn i {
  line-height: 50px;
}

.menu a:hover,
.show-menu-btn:hover,
.hide-menu-btn:hover {
  color: grey;
}

.paragrah {
  height: 50%;
  width: 30%;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 5em;
  margin-top: 7em;
  margin-bottom: 20em;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  text-align: justify;
}

#chk {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: -1111;
}

/*.content {
    padding: o 20px;

    img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 20px 0;
    }
}*/
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .header {
    display: none;
  }
  .search {
    display: none;
  }
  .header2 {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: none;
    position: fixed;
    height: 50px;
    background: #2D2524;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 10;
  }
  .background-img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .main {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 60px;
  }
  .mainInner {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .mainInner div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 3em;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 1.25px;
  }
  #sidebarSearch {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(1500px);
            transform: translateX(1500px);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    background: #000000;
    color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .sidebarIconSearch i {
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    right: 25px;
    z-index: 99;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ #sidebarSearch {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
  }
  input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ #sidebarSearch ~ .sidebarIconToggle {
    display: none;
  }
  .openSidebarSearch {
    float: right;
  }
  .search-title {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 20px 0 10px;
  }
  .search_text {
    outline: none;
    height: 30px;
    width: 60%;
    border: solid 3px #fff;
    background: none;
    border-radius: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  .tag-list {
    color: #000000;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .tag-list li {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin: 4px;
    height: 24px;
    width: 80px;
    -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
        justify-content: space-around;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .Category dt {
    background: #fff;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
  }
  .Category dt img {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
  }
  .Category dd {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .Category-list {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: space-evenly;
        -ms-flex-pack: space-evenly;
            justify-content: space-evenly;
  }
  .Day-box {
    outline: none;
    height: 30px;
    width: 200px;
    border: solid 3px #fff;
    background: none;
    border-radius: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  #sidebarMenu {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 50px;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-1500px);
            transform: translateX(-1500px);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    background: #000000;
  }
  .sidebarMenuInner {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 40%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
            transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .sidebarMenuInner li {
    list-style: none;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .sidebarMenuInner li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ #sidebarMenu {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
            transform: translateX(0);
  }
  input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ #sidebarMenu ~ .sidebarIconSearch {
    display: none;
  }
  input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ #sidebarMenu ~ #sidebarSearch {
    display: none;
  }
  input[type=checkbox] {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
    display: none;
  }
  .sidebarIconToggle {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 18px;
    left: 20px;
    height: 22px;
    width: 22px;
  }
  .spinner {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
  .horizontal {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 3px;
  }
  .diagonal.part-1 {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
  }
  .diagonal.part-2 {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 3px;
  }
  input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .sidebarIconToggle > .horizontal {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .sidebarIconToggle > .diagonal.part-1 {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
            transform: rotate(135deg);
    margin-top: 8px;
  }
  input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .sidebarIconToggle > .diagonal.part-2 {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
            transform: rotate(-135deg);
    margin-top: -9px;
  }
}

.image img {
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.event-name {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
}

.heart {
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-left: 17rem;
}

.event-date {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #FD8700;
}

.card-info {
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.save-mark {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.button {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 120px;
}

.seemore-btn {
  margin-top: 4rem;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.seemore-btn a {
  color: white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 4px 20px 4px 20px;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #7206F7;
}

.category-container {
  margin-top: 8rem;
}

.category-card {
  padding: 0 50px 80px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: space-evenly;
      -ms-flex-pack: space-evenly;
          justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.category-card p {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 35px;
}

.category-image {
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  border: solid #ffffff 1px;
}

.category-image img {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
          transition-duration: 0.5s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
}

.category-image img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
          transform: scale(1.1, 1.1);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .category-card {
    display: block;
  }
  .category-card-content {
    -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
    position: relative;
  }
  .category-card-content p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 43%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
            transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
    font-size: 45px;
  }
  .category-image {
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: solid 1px #ffffff;
  }
  .category-image img {
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
}

.use_contents {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.use_contents img {
  margin-right: 7rem;
  width: 20%;
}

.Description {
  text-align: center;
  width: 30%;
}

.Description p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 19px;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  color: #c7c7c7;
}

.register-btn {
  margin-top: 4rem;
}

.register-btn a {
  background-color: #F70661;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 4px 20px 4px 20px;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.find_func {
  margin: 1rem;
}

.use_contents2 img {
  margin-left: 7rem;
  margin-right: 0;
}

.start {
  margin: 4rem 0 10rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.right {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .use_contents {
    padding: 20px;
  }
  .use_contents img {
    margin-right: 1rem;
    width: 40%;
  }
  .use_contents2 {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .use_contents2 img {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 1rem;
  }
  .Description {
    width: 100%;
  }
  h4 {
    margin: 0;
  }
}

.login {
  background: url("../LPImages/danny-howe-bn-D2bCvpik-unsplash.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 80vh;
}

.login-contents {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  height: 80vh;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.login-base {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}

.login-base h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

.login-erea p {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
}

.login-box {
  margin: 12px 0;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  background: none;
  border-radius: 30px;
  height: 2.3em;
  width: 25em;
  outline: none;
  border: #fff solid 3px;
}

.login-link {
  margin-top: 2.5rem;
}

.login-link a {
  background-color: #0FCC41;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 4px 38px 4px 38px;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.forgot {
  margin-top: 0.8rem;
}

.forgot a {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 0.5px solid white;
}

.sns-icon-erea {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  margin: 2rem 0 0.5rem;
}

.sns-icon {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sns-icon i {
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 52%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.footer {
  height: 50vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2D2524;
}

/*@import "./footer";*/
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
}

h2 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  font-size: 38px;
}

h3 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 33px;
}

h4 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 23px;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.face {
  background: #305097;
}

.twi {
  background: #00aced;
}

.goo {
  background: #db4a39;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=main.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/css/swiper.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/swiper.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>landing page</title>
</head>
<body>
        <div class="header">
                <a href="#"><h1 class="logo">Dark Code</h1></a>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="chk">
                    <label for="chk" class="show-menu-btn">
                        <i class="fas fa-bars" style="color: white;"></i>
                    </label>        
                    <ul class="menu">
                    <div class="menu-list">
                        <a href="#">Register</a>
                        <a href="#">Events</a>
                        <a href="#">Login</a>
                        <label for="chk" class="hide-menu-btn">
                            <i class="fas fa-times" style="color: white;"></i>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </ul> 
            </div>


               
        <div class="header2">
            <input type="checkbox" class="openSidebarMenu" id="openSidebarMenu">
            <label for="openSidebarMenu" class="sidebarIconToggle">
              <div class="spinner diagonal part-1"></div>
              <div class="spinner horizontal"></div>
              <div class="spinner diagonal part-2"></div>
            </label>
          <div id="sidebarMenu">
            <ul class="sidebarMenuInner">
              <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Events</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Profile</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Log out</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        
        
        
        
          <input type="checkbox" class="openSidebarSearch" id="openSidebarSearch">
          <label for="openSidebarSearch" class="sidebarIconSearch">
            <i class="fas fa-search search_icon"></i>
          </label>
        
                <div id="sidebarSearch">
                  <div class="search-erea">
                    <div class="search-title">Enter the name of event</div>
                      <input type="text" class="search_text">
                      <div class="search-title">Choose tags</div>
                      <ul class="tag-list">
                        <li>Tag</li>
                        <li>Tag</li>
                        <li>Tag</li>
                        <li>Tag</li>
                      </ul>
                      <ul class="tag-list">
                        <li>Tag</li>
                        <li>Tag</li>
                        <li>Tag</li>
                        <li>Tag</li>
                      </ul> 
                    </div>
        
                    <div class="search-erea">
                      <div class="search-title">Categorys</div>
                      <div class="Category-list">
                        <dl class="Category">
                          <dt><img src="./image/martini.png" alt="bar-img"></dt>
                          <dd>bar</dd>
                        </dl>
                        <dl class="Category">
                          <dt><img src="./image/beer.png" alt="pub-img"></dt>
                          <dd>pub</dd>
                        </dl>
                        <dl class="Category">
                          <dt><img src="./image/dj.png" alt="club-img"></dt>
                          <dd>club</dd>
                        </dl>
                      </div>
                    </div>
        
                    <div class="search-erea">
                      <div class="search-title">Day</div>
                      <input type="text" class="Day-box">
                    </div>
        
                </div>
        
              </div>
            
        <div class="background-img">  
            <div class="main_search">
                <div class="search_content">
                    <form action="#" class="search">
                    <input type="text" class="search_text" placeholder="Enter the key words !">
                    <select name="select" id="select" class="Genre">
                            <option value="" hidden">genre</option>
                            <option value="1">bar</option>
                            <option value="2">pub</option>
                            <option value="3">club</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="date" class="search_date">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-search search_icon"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


  
      

    

    
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/js/swiper.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/js/swiper.min.js"></script>

    <script src="./js/swiper.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        var mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {
            // Optional parameters
            direction: 'horizontal',
            slidesPerView: 4,
            spaceBetween: 10,
            centeredSlides : true,
            loop: true,
        
            // Navigation arrows
            navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
            },
        
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

From a smartphone, it doesn't work, but if you check from PC, it works so I hope you can check this link from a smartphone.

thank you.

I checked both iOS and Android chrome browser.
And this issue is happening only in iOS.
So please check by iPhone.

Comment: As I checked in mobile browser chrome. it is working properly. which browser you are testing?

Comment: I checked both iOS and Android now. And when I checked from iOS google chrome, it didn't work. So this issue is happening only in iOS.

Comment: Okie. let me check with iOS because as I checked in android chrome it was working perfect.

Comment: I don't have an iPhone to test this on, but I would try giving `.background-img` a specific z-index (anything below `.header2`'s z-index, but probably just 0). Since it is a sibling of `.header2` and is not statically positioned but is below `.header2` in the DOM, it might be covering `.header2` up. You can also try setting a specific `top` or `bottom` value for your fixed-position elements, just to make sure they're not off-screen somehow. Even if they're 100% width and height, just a quick `top: 0` may help.

Comment: Thanks ! I will try !

Comment: It could be due to the `transform` property on an `absolute` positioned element. It is a well-known bug that appears on certain devices. The same issue occurs with a `fixed` positioned element. I found an article about a year ago on how to tackle the problem, but I'm having trouble digging it back up now.

Answer (score 0):

I also experience this issue on iOS devices time to time.

z-index behaves different on iOS (no matter the browser). Even if you correctly index content on Z axis, it won't be shown correctly on iOS devices.

Workaround is, giving container div a higher z-index than background.

In your case `#sidebarMenu {z-index: 100;}` should work.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it might be an issue with iOS.

According to the specs, the CSS property `z-index` should *only* not work if an element has the default positioning:

```
position: static
```

Consequently, to ensure that `z-index` works, *any* of the following may be applied to the element (which we can see you're already doing):

- `position: relative`
- `position: absolute`
- `position: fixed`
- `position: sticky`

---

**Further Reading:**

> **`position: static`**
> *The element is positioned according to the normal flow of the document. The top, right, bottom, left, and **z-index properties** have no
> effect. This is the default value.*

**Source:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#values